# Header menu links not working

Tags: html, web

Hi I keep wondering why the links on my header is not working, it keeps coming back from index.html over and over.Please help and thanks in advance.

```
        <div id="header-wrap" class="fixedheader">

            <!-- Primary Navigation
            ============================================= -->
            <nav id="primary-menu" class="style-2 center">

                <div class="container clearfix">

                    <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                    <ul class="divcenter">
                        <li><a href="index.html"><div>Home</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html"><div>WHO WE ARE</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="products.html"><div>WHAT WE TRADE</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html"><div>SERVICES</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="logistic.html"><div>LOGISTICS</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"><div>CONTACT</div></a></li>  
                    </ul>


            <!-- Logo
            ============================================= -->
            <div id="logo" class="divcenter">
                <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
                <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark@2x.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo@2x.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
            </div><!-- #logo end -->

                </div>

            </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->

        </div>


    </header><!-- #header end -->
```

Comment: So if you actually click one of those links the page does not change but stays at index.html all the time?

Comment: There is nothing here to help us answer your question. Your links look fine. Do you have some sort of code on your other pages that could potentially be re-directing users to the index page?

Comment: Have you checked the CSS file, may be some property causing this to happen. I would suggest to check this in more detail via developer console of google chrome.

Comment: Please try using a "/" infront of the actual HTML file name. Like this: href="/about.html"

Comment: @patrick yes exactly

Comment: @patrick I tried and still not working even adding "~/" still no luck

Comment: Are all of these html files in one single folder?

Comment: @patrick yes it is on the same folder

Comment: @jezz, do you have any error on your console?

Comment: @patrick I didn't encounter any error

Comment: Try to replace 'div' elements with 'span' inside links, if this not help, please create a jsfiddle sample of your code to be clear.

Comment: @mdameer here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/light22/yuwetcqu/#&togetherjs=ex9B9B9z9P

Comment: @mdameer I solved now the problem by removing the div clear fix

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing